# Next.js to Hostinger VPS

Tags: ubuntu, server, next.js, backend, vercel

I'd like to deploy my Next.js project to Hostinger but I have no idea how to set up the VPS part (Next.js won't work on their shared server) .
From what I see online, Vercel is the "easiest" way to deploy Next.js projects but I'd like to save some $$$$.
I looked at the set up of the Ubuntu server but I'd like to know if that is the best option for a Next.js project before moving forward.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction (I couldn't find anything useful online, maybe bc I don't know exactly where to start)?
Thanks everyone!

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-install-node-ubuntu Basically you need to install only NodeJS on your VPS and you are good to go.